# Getting Error on using DependsOnMethod in TestNG

Tags: testng

```
    @Test(priority = 13, enabled = true, dependsOnMethods = {"POM_Test.PaymentsTest.C2410997_FilterPaymentByPending"})
        public void C2410964_PendingBalanceOnHomePageAndMakePaymentPage()
                throws IOException, InterruptedException, ATUTestRecorderException, APIException{
            ///Some Code here.      
        }


@Test(priority = 28, enabled = false)
    public void C2410997_FilterPaymentByPending()
            throws IOException, InterruptedException, ATUTestRecorderException, APIException, AWTException, ParseException {
        //Some dependency is here. 


    }
```

Getting following error, `POM_Test.ATransactionTest2.C2410964_PendingBalanceOnHomePageAndMakePaymentPage() is depending on method public void POM_Test.PaymentsTest.C2410997_FilterPaymentByPending() throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.InterruptedException,atu.testrecorder.exceptions.ATUTestRecorderException,com.testrail.connection.APIException,java.awt.AWTException,java.text.ParseException, which is not annotated with @Test or not included`

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in the given code.

`C2410964_PendingBalanceOnHomePageAndMakePaymentPage`() depends on `C2410997_FilterPaymentByPending`() but

1. `C2410964_PendingBalanceOnHomePageAndMakePaymentPage`() has higher priority.
2. `C2410997_FilterPaymentByPending`() has attribute `enabled = false`

To make things work, please

1. don't mix using priority and dependsOnMethods. Preferred way is dependsOnMethods.
2. set the `enabled = true` for test `C2410997_FilterPaymentByPending`.

Comment: After enabled = true, it got working.. somehow i did not observe that..Thanks for the answer

Comment: It is running all the enabled test cases in the class (POM_Test.PaymentsTest) along with C2410997_FilterPaymentByPending. Is it the actual implementation?

Comment: Yes, this is intended behavior.

Comment: To avoid this we need to be the dependent test in the same class and not in the other class...? No other way right?

Comment: Sharing dependency across classes is evil. It is better to preserve the dependency within a class itself. This also makes the tests cleaner and makes the Single Responsibility Principle intact to some extent.